# Where to put the institute information in the article document class?

Tags: titles, document-classes

I've seen in other document classes that one can input the authors' institutes via special commands, for example in `revtex4` I can put

```
\title{Aggregation According to Classical Kinetics---From Nucleation to 
Coarsening}
\author{Yossi Farjoun}
\email{yfarjoun@math.mit.edu}
\thanks{Corresponding author}
\affiliation{G. Mill\'an Institute of Fluid Dynamics, Nanoscience and Industrial
Mathematics, Universidad Carlos III de Madrid, Spain}
\author{John C. Neu}%
\email{neu@math.berkeley.edu}
\affiliation{Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley}
```

and it gets typeset nicely:

[image]

--snip--

[image]

Is there a nice of doing the same with plain-old `article`?

Comment: I'm not sure you can add that to the standard title page, but you could use the [titling](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/) package to write a custom one.

Comment: Is using the Koma-Skript replacement for the standard classes an option? I.e. use `scrartcl` instead of plain `article` – that should have the relevant commands, too.

Comment: I'm also a bit lost. Do you mean the concept of `\institute` as a macro, or simply where to include it in the title data to get it to print?

Comment: Funny, maybe it was a permission issue. Thanks for reuploading it.

Answer (score 45):

The **authblk** package does this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Aggregation According to Classical Kinetics---From Nucleation to
Coarsening}

\author{Yossi Farjoun%
  \thanks{Electronic address: \texttt{yfarjoun@math.mit.edu}; Corresponding author}}
\affil{G. Mill\'an Institute of Fluid Dynamics,\\ Nanoscience and Industrial
Mathematics,\\ Universidad Carlos III de Madrid, Spain}

\author{John C. Neu%
  \thanks{Electronic address: \texttt{neu@math.berkeley.edu}}}
\affil{Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley}

\date{Dated: \today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Some tweaking to `\@maketitle` may be necessary, for example

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Large\bfseries \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\normalsize
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\normalsize \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

With this you'd get

[image]

Answer (score 15):

As `article` doesn't support it, you may use a `titlepage` environment. If you would like just to use the standard `\maketitle`, you could redefine this command or hook into the author macro.

The author is typeset using a simple table:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  \@author
\end{tabular}\par}
```

So, you could use `tabular` features inside the argument to `\author`. Simply use `\\` for a new row, perhaps several times. It would be set below and centered. Demonstrating tabular commands:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}
\title{Aggregation According to Classical Kinetics---From
    Nucleation to Coarsening}
\author{Yossi Farjoun \\
  \multicolumn{1}{p{.7\textwidth}}{\centering\emph{G. Mill\'an Institute
  of Fluid Dynamics, Nanoscience and Industrial Mathematics,
  Universidad Carlos III de Madrid, Spain}}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You could add further rows for further authors and institutes.

This is just a workaround and a demonstration what happens internally. I would recommend to use a `titlepage` environment instead of misusing the `article` `\maketitle` feature that isn't intended to be used with an institute.

Answer (score 7):

If for some reason you need compatibility with Beamer's `\institute` command, you can also add it to `\maketitle` using `etoolbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{% add institute to \maketitle
  \apptocmd{\@author}{\end{tabular}
    \par
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    #1}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Tester 1 \and Tester 2}
\institute{University of Testing \and University of Diagnostics}
\date{2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Maketitle example with institute]