# Adding more than one author with different affiliation

Tags: titles, authblk

My goal is adding more than one author with different affiliations, it will look like something:

```
Author A, Author B, Author C, Author D and Author E
       A,B,C Department of Computer Science
      D,E Department of Mechanical Engineering
         Email A,B,C,D,E @university.edu
                 Latex University
```

is that possible to do it without using any packages, if not packages are welcome.

Thanks

Edit:
i came up with Thorsten Donig's solution however i have the problem of symbols that appear weirdly.

[image]

Comment: Do you want this on a stand-alone title page or as part of of a title as it would be used for an article or paper? The `titlepage` environment (for stand-alone title pages) gives you freedom to typeset the authors just like you want,

Comment: Double column article.

Comment: I'd like a working answer to this question myself, using the symbols. Can anyone fix @ThorstenDonig's answer?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/where-to-put-the-institute-information-in-the-article-documentclass

Comment: @Canageek: I do not understand your question. You say you would like to duplicates achemso as closely as possible and then say the answer seems very similar already.  How do you want to fix the given answer? What should be removed? What should be added?

Comment: @Sony There is the bug in the answer that overlays a number with the symbol, then uses the number below instead of the symbol. It should use the symbols both above and below. I happen to know that Joseph Write is working on a solution to this though it may not be ready for a while.

Comment: @Canageek: I typeset (compiled) Thorsten Donig's code and got the same output (no bugs) as shown in his (accepted) answer.  I am using TeXLive 2011 and TeXShop.  I wonder (as Donig does) if it is due to an old version of a package.

Comment: You see how in the accepted answer there is a *1 after the first answer? If you read the question carefully, despite the fact that was accepted, he (and I) would like one that only uses *.

Comment: @Canageek did you see my answer below, it can solve your problem temporarily or as far as i remember the problem is solved after removing the \thanks{A.A@university.edu}. But in this case the problem is adding the e-mail addresses. So you can see my answer below to fix it.

Comment: Wow, I'm rather busy right now, but I'll make sure to try each one and give the reputation before the time expires. Thank you all.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

A short example with the [authblk](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package. It is not exactly what you are looking for, but comes quite close.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author B\thanks{B.B@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author C\thanks{C.C@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author D\thanks{D.D@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author E\thanks{E.E@university.edu}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
 authblk.sty    2009/11/18 1.3 (PWD)
 ***********
```

---

[image]

Comment: Donig, thanks i came up with ur solution however i have some problems, i uploaded the picture and edited my question, can you help me why this occurs?

Comment: @berkay: Unfortunately I can't comprehend this problem. I attached a picture of the resulting output. Perhaps a matter of outdated packages. See my list of used files. You can obtain this list by adding the `\listfiles` command as very first line to the sample code.

Comment: @ Thorsten Donig, the problem is solved after removing the \thanks{A.A@university.edu}, now is there any  other solution for adding the e-mail addresses:)

Comment: @berkay: Did you check your package versions as I suggested? As shown above it works fine for me. But you could abuse the `\date` command to insert the required information manually.

Comment: @Thorsten: can we change \*1 with 1\* after Author A? That is I need first the letter indicating the affiliation and then \* for the footnote.

Answer (score 34):

@Canageek: Is this what you want?
[image]

If so, then credit should go to Thorsten Donig as I read a "document" on authblk package and made few changes to Donig's answer.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[*]{Author A}
\author[*]{Author B}
\author[*]{Author C}
\author[**]{Author D}
\author[**]{Author E}
\affil[*]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[**]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Edit: If you want to use a dagger instead of ** , then replace (every) ** with $\dag$.

Comment: Very good, this works. It seems pretty much identical to the answer above, am I missing anything? What does the \rnewcommand at the bottom do?

Comment: I'm trying to add a new bounty with 50 rep for your work fixing it, if I can't...I'm sorry, thank you for your work.

Comment: It changes ", and" to " and".  If you prefer ", and" then comment it out.

Comment: No, I like yours better. Stupid Oxford comma. I've gone around and upvoted questions and answers of yours I like to make up for you not getting the bounty- You've probably got more reputation for that anyway.

Comment: I agree that this is simpler and works well

Comment: `\usepackage{titling}` seems to break this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

The [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package has capacities to typeset authors like this. See the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf) for the details.

Comment: Nowadays this wouldn't qualify as answer anymore

Answer (score 5):

@Canageek, 
I understand your concern so I hope my solution at that time will help you

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%use your conference package
\usepackage{usenix,epsfig,endnotes}
**\usepackage{authblk}**
\usepackage{enumitem}
%for math
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and

```
\begin{document}
%don't want date printed
\date{}
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{2}
%make title bold and 14 pt font (Latex default is non-bold, 16 pt)
\title{\Large \bf Paper Name here}
%\thanks {Use thanks if u you need it}
%for single author (just remove % characters)
\author[1]{\rm Name1}
\author[2]{\rm Name2}
\author[1,2]{\rm Name3}
\author[2]{\rm Name4}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}
\affil[2]{Department of Electrical Engineering}
\affil[ ]{X University}
\affil[ ]{Address Line}
\affil[ ]{\textit {\{email1,email2,email3,email4\}@xyz.edu}}

\maketitle
```

This solution worked for me. I hope it helps.
This will produce 1,2 not symbols. Many conferences has packages already supports the symbols for the authors however in my case the package of the conference was just deprecating the symbols. So I prefer just the numbers instead of the symbols.

Comment: usenix isn't in TeXLive so I can't test your solution. Is that package essential?

Comment: No, it's not you can use whatever you want even you can just delete it.

Comment: Alright, I got it working as you said. If I don't get a better option when reviewing the answers below I'll use this. Thank you. Also: Why are you using \bf in once place, and \textit in another? Old habits?

Comment: Actually, this seems to be identical to the answer below, except for the comment about $\dag$

Comment: I'm trying to add a new bounty with 50 rep for your work fixing it, if I can't...I'm sorry, thank you for your work.

Comment: I've gone over your questions and answers and tried to upvote things I liked to make up for not being able to award you the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with a solution without the use of additional packages (`authblk`). It gives almost exactly what the OP wants.

Basically, it provides a command `\affmark` which uses `\textsuperscript` to typeset the navigation symbols. The command takes an optional argument that specifies which symbol to use, which defaults to a star `*`. You can use `\dag`, `\ddag` etc like footnote, or numbers as in the following example.

```
% Use your conference documentclass or package.
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

% If your conference documentclass or package defines these macros,
% change these macros to different names.
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
% Don't want date printed
\date{}
% Make title large and bold
\title{\Large\bfseries Paper Name Here}

% Target typesetting:
%
% Author A, Author B, Author C, Author D and Author E
%        A,B,C Department of Computer Science
%       D,E Department of Mechanical Engineering
%          Email A,B,C,D,E @university.edu
%                  Latex University

\author{%
Author A\affmark[1], Author B\affmark[1], Author C\affmark[1], Author D\affmark[2], and Author E\affmark[2]\\
\affaddr{\affmark[1]Department of Computer Science}\\
\affaddr{\affmark[2]Department of Mechanical Engineering}\\
\email{\{A,B,C,D,E\}@university.edu}\\
\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And it produces:
[image: Output document]

Comment: How can I put the two affiliation lines into one line?

Comment: @Admia, you just delete the `\\ ` at the end of the first `\affaddr` line

Answer (score 3):

```
\title{Self-organizing and Self-reconfigurable \\
       Event Routing in Ad Hoc Networks \\with Causal Dependency Awareness}

\author{GUANHONG PEI and BINOY RAVINDRAN\\
       Virginia Tech
%       guanhong@vt.edu\\
%       binoy@vt.edu\\
\and
% 3rd. author
E.D. JENSEN\\
       The MITRE Corporation
%       jensen@mitre.org\\
```

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35309/align-author-blocks for a variation of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{document}

\title{TITLE OF DOCUMENT
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{author1\affmark[1], author2\affmark[2]}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{\affmark[1,2]School of Computer Science and Engineering} \\
\textit{\affmark[1,2]ABCUniversity}\\
\affmark[1,2]city, India \\
\affmark[1]author1@email.com, \affmark[2]author2@email.com}

}

\maketitle
```

It can be used for IEEE papers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you extend your answer and add some explanations?

Answer (score 0):

A quick temporary way. Just add spaces before the superscript.

Try

```
\author[\space\space 1]{Your Name \thanks{Address}}
```

instead of

```
\author[1]{Your Name \thanks{Address}}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Without any other Latex packages.**

[image]

```
\author{
Author A$^1$~~~
Author B$^1$~~~
Author C$^1$~~~
Author D$^2$~~~
Author E$^2$~~~
\smallskip 
\\
$^1$Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University
\\
$^2$Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University
}
```