# Align author blocks

Tags: positioning, titles

I want to align the author blocks into both lines and columns. My desired output is shown as below:

```
  Author 1               Author 2
Affiliation 1          Affiliation 2

  Author 3               Author4
Affiliation 3          Affiliation 4
```

What is the best way to do this with `IEEEtran`? I tried `\author \and`, but it cannot align columns also. Can we do it without using `minipage`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185867/align-author-blocks-in-latex?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With option `conference` or `peerreviewca` you may use `\and`. But if your group of author name and affiliation is to small, the four groups will be placed horizontal:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{%
  Author 1\\Affilation 1
  \and Author 2\\Affiliation 2
  \and Author 3\\Affiliation 3
  \and Author 4\\Affiliation 4
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may simply fake need of more horizontal width at each group:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{%
  \makebox[.5\linewidth]{Author 1}\\Affilation 1\\
  \and \makebox[.5\linewidth]{Author 2}\\Affiliation 2\\
  \and \makebox[.5\linewidth]{Author 3}\\Affiliation 3\\
  \and \makebox[.5\linewidth]{Author 4}\\Affiliation 4\\
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]