# Is the number of authors restricted in article?

Tags: line-breaking, titles

At the begining of the `.tex` file I put

```
\title{title here}

\author{name 1
       \and name 2
       \and name 3 
       \and name 4 
       \and name 5 \\ 
       \small institution\\
       \small department \thanks{thanks here}}
```

but in the PDF file (`\maketitle`) it gets 2 names in the same line, and the other names and institution are in separate lines. How can I fix this so I can have all the names in separate lines? I tried with `\\` between the ones that are in the same line but it doesn't work?

Comment: The [`authblk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package provides an easy way to do this. See this question for a slightly more complex version of what you want. [Adding more than one author with different affiliation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9594/2693). Alternatively, you could use a simple `{tabular}` inside the `\author` command.

Comment: Still, the actual question remains unanswered: Is the number of authors restricted?

Comment: The answer is `NO`. In my answer I have added nine authors and one can add more.  We can put many authors without restriction and using `authblk` we can format neatly. `authblk can manage the affiliations for `n` number of authors without any trouble. for details one can refer the documentation of `authblk`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with `authblk` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk} % < ---------you can add the option [noblocks] for names in the same line
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\Authfont{\small}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\footnotesize}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Title here}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\author[1]{Author -- 1\footnote{Corresponding author}}
\author[1]{Author -- 2}
\author[1]{Author -- 3}
\author[1]{Author -- 4}
\author[2]{Author -- 5}
\author[2]{Author -- 6}
\author[2]{Author -- 7}
\author[2]{Author -- 8}
\author[2]{Author -- 9}
\affil[1]{Department of Physics, Your Institute,}
\affil[2]{Department of Physics, Another Institute}
\maketitle
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{abstract}
Your abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\section{Section goes here}
%=================================================================
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details from command prompt run `texdoc authblk`.

Comment: +1, but are all of `\usepackage{fullpage,xspace,setspace,amsmath,lscape}` really necessary? We like to keep solutions minimal, i.e. they should only contain what's needed to solve the OP's problem. The same applies to `[a4paper,12pt]`. The abstract and section title are alright to give you a better impression of what a document would look like, I'd say.

Comment: How would you manually specify where to insert a line break into the author list?