# Compilation error with tex4ht when using the authblk package

Tags: tex4ht, authblk

The following example, taken from [Adding more than one author with different affiliation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/adding-more-than-one-author-with-different-affiliation) and saved as `example.tex`, compiles well with `pdflatex example.tex`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author B\thanks{B.B@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author C\thanks{C.C@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author D\thanks{D.D@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author E\thanks{E.E@university.edu}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

But with `mk4ht oolatex example.tex` I get three times the error message "**! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@author.**" and not the desired output file.

Comment: I think the reason for this is that mk4ht doesn't understand the authblk package. After all mk4ht doesn't support most packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authblk` redefines standard LaTeX commands, such as `\maketitle` and `\author`. As these commands are redefined by `tex4ht` as well, it is not surprise that they clash each other. The fix is easy in this case. Save the following code as `authblk.4ht`:

```
\def\maketitle{\bgroup%
  \AB@maketitle%
\egroup}

\endinput
```

This fixes `\maketitle` definition provided by `authblk` and your can be compiled without errors.

[image]