# \maketitle print the below mentioned formats

Tags: titles

- I am using `article` class file. I need the output each author command
  will be printed in seperate authors. But the output is printed last
  authors only.
- How to implement the optional box values like `[aff={1}]`. Kindly
  provide the ideas.
- How to print the abstract text before the maketitle. Kindly provide
  the ideas

The below mentioned coding is insert inside the tex file:

```
\author[aff={1}]{Rahuman}
\author[aff={2}]{Kumaran}
\address{address one}
\address{address two}
```

My Required ouput is:

```
Rahuman1, Kumaran2
1 address one
2 address one
```

Comment: Use `authblk` package and you have several options there.

Comment: Maybe related: [Adding more than one author with different affiliation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/adding-more-than-one-author-with-different-affiliation)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure, but this may be what you are after:

```
\author{Rahuman\thanks{address one} \and Kumaran\thanks{address two}}
```