# Author footnote with number

Tags: footnotes, titles

I would like to schedule the authors with numbers and not symbols.
Using the code below the authors are marked with symbols.
Is important that the description appears as a footnote.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\title{Bla}
\author{Rafael \footnotemark[1]}

\begin{document}
\footnotetext[1]{Note...}
\maketitle

Blablabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9598/31323). Maybe there is an easier solution, but the [`authblk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy with the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Bla}
\author{Rafael \thanks{Note…}}

\thanksmarkseries{arabic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blablabla
\end{document}
```

[image]