# Add separate footnote for an author

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, affiliation

I need to insert a footnote for the third author, and I am using **\footnotetext** for it.

```
\author{Bleh \and Bleh Bleh \and Bleh Bleh Bleh\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{Right. Works.}
```

This gives me the following error.

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 84.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

I have checked that it is introduced by footnotemark because if I remove it, it compiles.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the command `\thanks{note}`.
If you wan't numbers please see [Author footnote with number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196758/author-footnote-with-number) and for a more well versed answer [How to write a footnnote attached to the author in a LaTeX paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/how-to-write-a-footnnote-attached-to-the-author-in-a-latex-paper)