# Missing superscript on author

Tags: titles

**The problem**

I use the [template](http://www.iospress.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/jaise_latex_template.zip) from IOS Press to write my paper. It gives us a sample pdf with its tex file (`jiase2e.tex`), where each author has superscript:

[image: Template provided by Press]
However, if I compile it on my computer using `pdflatex`, the superscripts are replaced by question marks (`?`):

[image: Template compiled on my computer]

**The code**

I just use the `jiase2e.tex` file it provides to us, and never change it. There's part of the tex file:

```
\documentclass{jaise2e}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}%

\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphics}


\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}


\firstpage{1} \lastpage{5} \volume{1} \pubyear{2009}


\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}                           % The preamble begins here.

%
%\pretitle{Pretitle}
\title{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX\thanks{Footnote in title.}}

\runningtitle{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}


\author[A]{\fnms{First} \snm{Author}\thanks{Corresponding author. E-mail: editorial@iospress.nl.}\thanks{Do not use capitals for the author's surname.}},
\author[B]{\fnms{Second} \snm{Author}}
and
\author[B]{\fnms{Third} \snm{Author}}
\runningauthor{F. Author et al.}
\address[A]{Journal Production Department, IOS Press, Nieuwe Hemweg 6b, 1013 BG, Amsterdam,\\ The Netherlands\\
E-mail: first@somewhere.com}
\address[B]{Department first, then University or Company name, Insert a complete correspondence (mailing) address,
Abbreviate US states, Include country\\
E-mail: \{second,third\}@somewhere.com}
...
\end{frontmatter}
...
\end{document}
```

**What I have tried**

As a newbie to LaTex, I only come up with an ugly workaround to add superscripts to authors manually:

```
\author{First Author\textsuperscript{a}\thanks{Corresponding author. E-mail: editorial@iospress.nl.}\thanks{Do not use capitals for the author's surname.}},
\author{Second Author\textsuperscript{b}}
and
\author{Third Author\textsuperscript{b}}
```

which works fine but not decent.

On the other hand, I add a line `\usepackage{authblk}` to `jiase2e.tex` file as suggested by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/adding-more-than-one-author-with-different-affiliation) but without luck:

```
\documentclass{jaise2e}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}%

\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{authblk}   % I add this package

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}


\firstpage{1} \lastpage{5} \volume{1} \pubyear{2009}


\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}                           % The preamble begins here.

%
%\pretitle{Pretitle}
\title{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX\thanks{Footnote in title.}}

\runningtitle{Instructions for the preparation of a camera-ready paper in \LaTeX}
%\subtitle{Subtitle}


\author[A]{First Author\thanks{Corresponding author. E-mail: editorial@iospress.nl.}\thanks{Do not use capitals for the author's surname.}},
\author[B]{Second Author}
and
\author[B]{Third Author}
\runningauthor{F. Author et al.}
\address[A]{Journal Production Department, IOS Press, Nieuwe Hemweg 6b, 1013 BG, Amsterdam,\\ The Netherlands\\
E-mail: first@somewhere.com}
\address[B]{Department first, then University or Company name, Insert a complete correspondence (mailing) address,
Abbreviate US states, Include country\\
E-mail: \{second,third\}@somewhere.com}
```

there are no authors this time at all:

[image: no authors at all]

Is it possible to fix it? Thanks.

P.S.: I use FreeBSD 10 on my x86-64 computer, and have latest (20140525_1) `print/texlive-full` installed from `ports system`.

Comment: You just need to run `(pdf)latex` twice.

Comment: @IanThompson Cool! Really Nice! Running it twice fixes the issue, thanks. But just curious to know why should we do it twice.

Comment: `LaTeX` writes certain information that it needs to a file with the extension `.aux`. It needs this information to insert references, etc. so you often have to run it twice (or even three times if certain packages are used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IanThompson points out, running `pdflatex jiase2e.tex` ***twice*** fixes the issue.