# Author names running over margins

Tags: margins, titles, affiliation, authblk

I am trying to write a paper that looks similar to the one in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277451/multiple-authors-with-affiliations-in-acl-style). I am using the `naaclhlt2016` template (required), available [here](http://naacl.org/naacl-pubs/). Below is an MWE of what I have:

```
%
% File naaclhlt2016.tex
%

\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{naaclhlt2016}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\naaclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}


\title{Instructions for NAACL HLT 2016 Proceedings - This stays within the margins}


\author[1]{Author 1 who has a very very long name}
\author[2]{Author 2 who also has a very very very long name}
\author[1]{Author 2 who has a very very very long name}
\affil[1]{Department of Linguistics, University}
\affil[2]{School of Medicine, University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:
[image: resulting pdf]

How can I get the author names to stay within the margins?

**EDIT**: My actual article has the following libraries loaded.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{naaclhlt2016}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{apacite}
```

Comment: The template doesn't use `authblk` and that's precisely the problem. The instructions are not crystal clear, but not too obscure either.

Comment: Interesting. Is one of the packages masking it?

Comment: In other words, use what they want, and not `authblk`.

Comment: I haven't found a way to get the desired output using their template, though.

Comment: You have to use *their style*.

Comment: I answered in order to help you into finding the correct way to submit your paper. I'll remove my answer, because apparently you didn't like to be told the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the used command `\outauthor` to print the author(s).  Add to your preamble the following code (change `p{13cm}` to the value you need):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\outauthor{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\centering}p{13cm}} % <========================
    \ifnaaclfinal 
         \bf\@author
    \else 
        % Avoiding common accidental de-anonymization issue. --MM
            \bf Anonymous NAACL submission
    \fi
    \end{tabular}}
\makeatother
```

Command `>{\centering}` is used to get a centered list of authors and affiliations. You have to call package `array` for this.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{naaclhlt2016}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array} % for >{\centering}

\naaclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\outauthor{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\centering}p{13cm}} % <==========================
    \ifnaaclfinal 
         \bf\@author
    \else 
        % Avoiding common accidental de-anonymization issue. --MM
            \bf Anonymous NAACL submission
    \fi
    \end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc ib}\TeX}


\title{Instructions for NAACL HLT 2016 Proceedings - This stays within the margins}


\author[1]{Author 1 who has a very very long name}
\author[2]{Author 2 who also has a very very very long name}
\author[1]{Author 2 who has a very very very long name}
\affil[1]{Department of Linguistics, University}
\affil[2]{School of Medicine, University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I was not referring to a space. I'm just referring to centering the author part and keeping the affiliation part left-justified.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite understand the last 2 questions.

Comment: @Adam_G I guess you are writing a official paper and the institution advised you to use a special style (you use in the given mwe). If that is so, are you allowed to change there style? Usually you have to use their style without changings ...  Changing their style code result that they do not want to accept your paper ...