# titlepage setting

Tags: titles

I have a problem with the title page of my paper. The code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\renewcommand{\hoffset}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\voffset}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\title{{\LARGE \bfseries The title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title \thanks{adc}}}
\date{}
\author{First Author\thanks{\textit{Corresponding author.} Address: School of Whatsoever, University of No Place, The new but old Building, 10 Wherever Road, X11 11X, London, UK. Phone: +44 (0)123456789. Email: mine@noplace.ac.uk. } \\
University of No Place \and Second Author \thanks{Address: School of Another topic, University of Another Place, The new but old Building, 10 Wherever Road, X11 11X, London, UK}\\
University of Another Place \and Third Author \thanks{Address: School of Another topic, University of Another Place, The new but old Building, 10 Wherever Road, X11 11X, London, UK}\\
University of Another Place}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1ex}
\begin{center}
First version: First version 01 June 2016 \\ This version: 20/06/2016
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \lipsum[3-4] \bigskip

Keywords: First keyword, second keyword, third keyword

JEL Classification: XXX, XXX

\pagebreak
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The two problems are the following:

a) Is it possible to change the setting of the front page only such that it comes in one page? Notice that I would like to change the setting of the front page, but I am keen with the one for the other pages in my paper, in which case I would like to maintain the setlength indicated in my code;

b) As you can see the three authors share one affiliation (University of Another Place). In the footnote I do not like to repeat the address for all the three, but I would like to use the same symbol to connect them to the same address (of course the first author will have two address, the one for the University of No Place and the second which is common to the other two authors).

Does someone have an hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a)I think you should have a look at the `geometry`-package. It will make setting up the page a lot easier, and I suspect your settings here is not really what you want. Try something like `\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}`,

b) Why not just put the authors together? `Second Author \& Third Author`

Comment: @runartrollet. Thanks for point a). Regarding point b) I prefer to have each author with his affiliation. Nonetheless, it does not solve the point with respect to First Author that shares one affiliation with Second Author and Third Author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work the problem out. This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{{\LARGE \bfseries The title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title \thanks{adc}}}
\date{}
\author{First Author\thanks{\textit{Corresponding author.} Address: School of Whatsoever, University of No Place, The new but old Building, 10 Wherever Road, X11 11X, London, UK. Phone: +44 (0)123456789. Email: mine@noplace.ac.uk. } {\footnotemark[3]} \\ %include the space
University of No Place \\ University of Another Place \and Second Author \thanks{Address: School of Another topic, University of Another Place, The new but old Building, 10 Wherever Road, X11 11X, London, UK}\\ % This is the third footnote including the one in the title.
University of Another Place \and Third Author \footnotemark[3]\\
University of Another Place}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1ex}
\begin{center}
First version: First version 01 June 2016 \\ This version: 20/06/2016
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \lipsum[3-4] \bigskip

Keywords: First keyword, second keyword, third keyword

JEL Classification: XXX, XXX

\pagebreak
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is what I manage to do using  runartrollet comment and [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9598/75648). I've used `geometry` package and [`authblk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk?lang=en).

This is for point a), only odd pages with margin zero and first page with custom margins.

[image]

This is for point b), one author share address and affiliation with the others.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} %use twoside so geometry knows left/right pages

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,lmargin=0cm]{geometry} % only odd pages get margin zero

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
%\setlength{\leftmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
%\renewcommand{\hoffset}{1cm}
%\renewcommand{\voffset}{1cm}
\usepackage{authblk}


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm} %new settings for first page only
\title{{\LARGE \bfseries The title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title the title \thanks{adc}}}
\date{}
\author[1,2]{First Author }
\author[2]{Second Author }
\author[2]{Third Author }
\affil[1]{University of No Place \thanks{Adress of No Place}}
\affil[2]{University of Another Place \thanks{Adress of Another Place}}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1ex}
\begin{center}
First version: First version 01 June 2016 \\ This version: 20/06/2016
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent \lipsum[3-4] \bigskip

Keywords: First keyword, second keyword, third keyword

JEL Classification: XXX, XXX

\pagebreak
\end{abstract}

\restoregeometry % goes back to original geoemtry settings

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it is not the one I need. I was able to work this problem out. I am posting the code in a second.