# What are the default settings of the "article" document class?

Tags: formatting, document-classes, article

I tried looking for the documentation from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/article) but the PDF linked isn't the correct one, the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201033/where-can-i-find-the-manual-for-the-standard-class-article-of-latex) give the same PDF, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by default settings? just which class options are set or all the default fonts and list spacing etc which is the full code of the class file? If you mean the class options, it does `\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}`

Comment: yes that is what I mean, thank you, may I ask where can I find such things?

Comment: line 111 of article.cls

Comment: I meant in general for other document classes like report and assignment

Comment: look in the package doc, or as I did open  the file and search for `\ExecuteOptions`

Comment: The PDF that you reference in the question (but you say is not correct) has this information for article, report and book, see page 6.

Comment: thank you, all clear

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because suggestions given in comments were acknowledged by OP to provide the needed answer.