# Footnote on the title page in an article

Tags: footnotes, titles, authblk

I need my e-mail address to appear as a footnote on the title page. I tried using `authblk.sty` but the footnote appears after the date in the middle of the title page. My file looks like:

```
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\begin{document}
\author{First Last
\thanks{E-mail: \textttt{me@x.edu}}}
\affil{Department, College}
\date{\today}

\maketitle
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

I started from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/where-to-put-the-institute-information-in-the-article-document-class). What's the best to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a `\vfill` like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\title{Aggregation According to Classical Kinetics---From Nucleation to
Coarsening}

\author{First Last%
  \thanks{E-mail: \texttt{me@x.edu}}}
\affil{Department, College}


\date{\today}

\maketitle
\vfill
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Test 1st section}
\blindtext
\section{Second section}
\blindtext
\subsection{test subsection}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!